# Will adding top level directories with similar structure to existing directories change the SEO of my site?

Tags: seo, url, subdirectory

I've been pointed this way for SEO related questions and this one has had me pondering for a little while now.

I'm recreating a site's structure. The website's content is generated through several feeds and unless I want to place each and every - of the 10,000 odd - venues into their own category manually, I can't avoid categorising each item by using its address.

The current the structure looks like this

```
Homepage > region > county > city/town > venue page
```

and the URL looks like `domain/region/county/city/venue/`

I'm relatively happy to use this structure as it's not too convoluted. However we also promote deals and we also group the venues into their respective franchise, so that leads to URLs such as:

`domain/groups` AND `domain/deals`

My question is: how would the directory structure look with these new additions?

Would I have a URL that looks like `domain/deals/region/county/city/venue` or `domain/group/region/county/city/venue` and just put a 301 or a canonical link tag on the page to prevent the duplicate pages competing with each other?

Am I just worrying about it needlessly and perhaps link straight from `domain/deals` to the venue page URL `domain/region/county/city/venue`, this bothers me a bit though as the deals and groups will not be in the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specific URLs don't matter too much for SEO.  Google is very good at crawling and indexing pretty much any URL structure you throw at it.  Most of the ranking differences from URLs come from usability.  For usability, URLs should be:

- descriptive
- short

  - Users might actually be able to type shorter URLs
  - Shorter URLs have less cruft in them so users can see just the important bits
  - URLs over 80 characters often get truncated by email software, forum software, and content management systems.
- memorable

I would not choose to put as much information into the URLs as you have.  The ideal URL for a venue would probably be just `/venue-name`  If there are multiple venues with the same name, you might have to differentiate with some geographic information `/city-state/venue`.

Your breadcrumbs don't have to match your URL directory structure.

Multiple pages about each venue shouldn't be duplicate content as long as:

- You have different content (your page about deals sounds different)
- You write different titles and meta descriptions

Again, the URL tat you choose for these new pages, will have very little impact on your rankings.  Do whatever works for you and search engines will be able to index it.

Comment: so i'm needlessly worrying again, gotcha ;) thanks.